# Highcharts Map: Unable to plot data in world map from city names

Tags: highcharts

Expected behaviour
Able to plot data from city names

Actual behaviour
I'm able to plot the data using country subregion but it is not working for city names

[Live demo - fiddle url](http://jsfiddle.net/5ejzk2w7)

```
chart: {
    map: 'countries/fr/fr-all-all'
},

title: {
    text: 'Highmaps basic demo'
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/fr/fr-all-all.js">France, admin2</a>'
},

mapNavigation: {
    enabled: true,
    buttonOptions: {
        verticalAlign: 'bottom'
    }
},

colorAxis: {
    min: 0
},

series: [{
    data: data,
    name: 'Random data',
    joinBy: ['name', 'code'],
    states: {
        hover: {
            color: '#BADA55'
        }
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '{point.name}'
    }
}]
```

Product version
5.0.14

Comment: Hi @Dharmarajan, Could you decribe your problem more precisely? How would you like  present data for a city?

Comment: I'm trying to plot data in world map using city names. I'm getting city names (Example: San Antonio, Mumbai) from third party sources. I'm able to plot map using lat and long but unable to plot using city names.

Comment: Could you add to the question a sample of data structure that you want to dsiplay?

Comment: @ppotaczek - Please find the below fiddle URL for data structure reference.
https://jsfiddle.net/dharmarajan/on53d197/
I'm try to acheive using city names without lat and long.

Comment: You can't use just city names without lat/lon. Highmaps doesn't have any stored position of cities.

Comment: Thank you @ppotaczek.